# How to assign a particular instance mount on EC2 to HDFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hdfs, hadoop2

I am trying to install single node hadoop cluster using i2 instance and I am looking to assign one of the instance store mount of 800 GB SSD dedicated to HDFS but not sure how to do it.

The default i2 instance comes with 2 800 GB SSD instance stores and I want to dedicate one of them to HDFS and other one to some other work load.

/dev/xvdb --Mounted it to /mnt/hdfs ---I want to make sure all my HDFS data is stored in here 
/dev/xvdc --Mounted it to /mnt/data
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Assume you aware that instance store data will not survive if you issue a EC2 "stop" instead of reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The file /etc/fstab controls what gets mounted where at boot.
Assuming those folders exist (and the block devices you list are correct) you just need to add a couple of lines:

```
/dev/xvdb       /mnt/hdfs   ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
/dev/xvdc       /mnt/data   ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
```

I've made some assumptions here for you (that they're ext4 formatted for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing, configuring and managing Hadoop yourself, an alternative is to use **Amazon EMR**, which provides a Hadoop system.

Amazon EMR **automatically uses Instance Store for HDFS**, but you can also request Amazon EBS volumes to extend HDFS (or on instance types that do not provide Instance Store).